# Does GEKKO support any gradient-free methods for discrete integer space problem?

Tags: gekko

dear experts of GEKKO,

Since the problem I'm going to solve has no closed math form and the solution falls in discrete integer space like, the gradient-free method should work. Thus, as far as you know, do you know if GEKKO support any gradient-free method with the related example for now?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Gekko itself could support any solution method but there is currently no linked solver that takes that solution approach. Currently all are Nonlinear Programming (NLP) or Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming (MINLP) solvers that use derivatives from Gekko automatic differentiation.

There is a list of [derivative-free optimizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative-free_optimization). Perhaps there is another Python package that could better handle your problem. There is also additional information in the [Design Optimization Course](https://apmonitor.com/me575) and the online [Design Optimization Book (Chap 5 and 6)](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/BookChapters) on gradient-free methods such as Simulated Annealing and Genetic Algorithms.